# Regex for removing parts of the string

Tags: python, regex

How to solve this problem on regex in Python?

I want to filter words `regular` and `text` from:

```
"A regular expression is a special text string for describing a search pattern."
```

I want the result like this :

```
"A expression is a special string for describing a search pattern."
```

Please help me to solve this problem on regex syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

txt = "A regular expression is a special text string for describing a search pattern."
pattern = "(.*) regular(.*) text(.*)"

result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2\3", txt)

print(result)    # for testing only
```

---

**The explanation:**

As you can see, your regular expression is

```
(.*) regular(.*) text(.*)
```

Expressions in parentheses are so called *capture groups*. All 3 have the same form:

```
.*
```

which means that they will match everything - `.` means *any character*, `*` means *arbitrary number of them*, including zero (empty string).

Now we may use the captured texts as `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, respectively, so your original text is in this notation the same as

```
\1 regular\2 text\3
```

So in the re.sub() function we keep as substituting string only

```
\1\2\3
```

which effectively strip out the parts `" regular"` and `" text"`.

Comment: thanks for your attention and your answer. God bless you. :-)

Comment: hhmm sorry, Why your syntaks not work on this text?
" saya sedang akan di warung pak budi. saya membeli bakwan seharga Rp. 200"
I want to remove word "saya" from this text

can you help me one more time? thanks

Comment: Use this: `pattern = "(.*) saya (.*) saya(.*)"` (if your text really starts with a space; if it is not the case, remove the first occurrence of a space from the pattern, too).